# Paint for microwave interior

Tags: microwave-oven

I accidently removed our microwave's interior paint by spraying the interior with an oven cleaner (my wife told me to do it).

What paint can I use to to repaint the interior? Our microwave is expensive so I prefer to repaint it if possible. I searched Amazon for "microwave cavity paint" but it's either out-of-stock or discontinued.

I read in the Internet that I can use Enamel paint. Is that correct?

Comment: Just use regular appliance epoxy spray, that's what the 'special" microwave paints are. They just label it special and charge twice as much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microwave cavity paint comes up on my Amazon page...

QB Products 98QBP0302 Microwave Cavity Paint, 6 oz, Snow White
by Appliance Pros
Learn more: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00IU6MNAG/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_uKlMFb0DB31Q0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IU6MNAG)

Comment: It's unavailable "We don't know when or if this item will be back in stock."

Comment: I found a different seller that has it in-stock.